# Rendering DICOM image using Fellow Oak DICOM

Tags: c#, asp.net, dicom, fo-dicom

I need to extract a DICOM image from a file and convert it to a standard bitmap. This is the code I have, using fo-dicom:

```
    Bitmap bmp;
    try
    {
        var image = new DicomImage(Context.Server.MapPath("~/IM-0001-0000.dcm"));
        bmp = new Bitmap(image.RenderImage());
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //for breakpoint purposes
        throw;
    }
```

However, it fails with the following message:

```
No codec registered for tranfer syntax: JPEG 2000 Image Compression
```

I'm not an expert on medical imaging, and Google doesn't turn up anything useful. I installed fo-dicom via NuGet, so I suppose all required references are already in the project. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not finding documentation for this new-ish lib, you might have better luck trying out their support forum, on which [here is one post](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fo-dicom/DYZglkKgFbE) regarding the same error message (though different transfer syntax), perhaps this post can be of some help.

Comment: @ChrisO Yep, I've seen this post, still no luck. And AFAIK, there is no documentation. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: ClearCanvas (open source) is a more mature SDK, so it might support JPEG 2000 out of the box.  MergeCom (payware) might also support this.  Though I've worked with DICOM for some years now, never had a need to support JPEG 2000, that format never really took off.  FWIW, common radiology datasets tend to be JPEG Lossless (or uncompressed) and cardiology datasets tend to be JPEG lossy.

Comment: @ChrisO I tried a few more files and managed to open a raw one, but neither of JPEG variations seem to work. I guess I'll try ClearCanvas, though it seems to be way too complicated for something that shouldn't be more than 3 lines of code in a student project.

Comment: OK, I just tried a JPEG 2000 sample with fo-dicom from NuGet, I can decompress a sample file just fine, don't get the `no codec` error message.  I think the clue is that your ASP.NET app is having problems loading the native DLLs, let me try to find some advice on that problem.  ASP has some weirdness with paths for native DLLs, could be that it cannot find them which might lead to the codec error.

Comment: Here is some advice regarding fo-dicom and ASP.NET: [post from fo-dicom Google groups](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fo-dicom/uk7FkDS05s4).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the target platform from 64 bit to 32 bit.
this is how you can do it on visual studio 2013, but must be pretty much the same in other versions
project tab-->properties-->build tab-->platform target

Answer (score 0):

I'm using fo-dicom 2.0.2, had same issues, fixed by coping Dicom.Native.dll in same directory as .exe and install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: The most reliable method to include the native codec DLL:s is that you make sure *Platform Target* (project properties, *Build* tab) is set to **x64** or **x86**. If *Platform Target* is set to any other value (for example *Any CPU*), then build script does not know which native DLL to pick, and you should see a warning message in the build output recommending you to select *x64* or *x86*. See [@srinced's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36482175/650012) response above.

Comment: Indeed, I have those warnings, but when I had the problem "No codec registered for transfer syntax" I've tried all options ( x64 , x86 and any CPU) with no luck. I didn't had any problem when runing directly from the project, had problem with some other computers and solved by instaling 2013 vcredist_x86. The weird part is that in my Visual Studio 2013 at Platform I can only chose "Active (any CPU)", I can change only Target CPU

Comment: Please note that it **is not** the solution platform in the VS toolbar you should change, but the *Platform Target* in the *Build* tab of your project's Properties page. *Platform Target* may very well be set to *Any CPU* even when the selected solution platform is *x86* or *x64*.

Comment: Thank Mr. Anders, found the Configuration Manager and added x86 CPU and the warnings disappear. I didn't care that much since the application worked just fine even so. Learned something new so thank again